# Correct way to build python executable(in wxWidgets) so that it can be called from another wxWidgets application?

Tags: python, wxpython, pyinstaller

I have two wxWidgets Python applications - t1 and t2. The source code directory structure for two applications are as follows:
   GUI/t1/...
   GUI/t2/...

I have a button in t1 for launching t2. I'm trying to build t1 and t2 using pyinstaller, so that t2 can be correctly launched from t1. I built both t1 and t2 inside the GUI/t1/bin directory. So, the t1.exe and t2.exe are present are as follows:

GUI/t1/bin/dist/t1/t1.exe
GUI/t1/bin/dist/t2/t2.exe

I'm able to launch t1 and t2 successfully by clicking on their respective executables. But, when I try to start t2 from t1, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<string>", line 15, in <module>  
  File "c:\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 386, in importHook
    mod = _self_doimport(nm, ctx, fqname)  
  File "c:\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 480, in doimport
    exec co in mod.__dict__  
  File "bin\build\pyi.win32\jobmanager\out00-PYZ.pyz\wx", line 45, in <module>  
  File "c:\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 386, in importHook
    mod = _self_doimport(nm, ctx, fqname)  
  File "c:\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 480, in doimport
    exec co in mod.__dict__  
  File "bin\build\pyi.win32\jobmanager\out00-PYZ.pyz\wx._core", line 4, in <modu
le>  
  File "c:\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 409, in importHook
    raise ImportError("No module named %s" % fqname)  
ImportError: No module named _core_
```

t2 is launched from t1 as below:

output = subprocess.check_output("../t2/t2.exe",stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

I'm not sure what the issue is. What's the correct way to launch t2 from t1 or do I need to change anything on the build? Copying t2.exe to dist/t1 and launching as subprocess.check_output("t2.exe",...) does not help too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to version 2.0 of pyinstaller. On changing the version of pyinstaller to 2.1 and re-building both executables solves the issue.